# CSS sub-menu wont display vertically, keeps aligning horizontally

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, menu

Been banging my head of this all day and can't figure out how to correct it

Basically i have created a dropdown mega menu from the "services" link on my main navigation but my sub-menu keeps on taking on the attributes of the parent navigation menu.

I want the dropdown menu to display vertically underneath the title and text but the elements are aligned horizontally like the main navigation and nothing i have tried will correct it.

See fiddle for example:  http://jsfiddle.net/DannyW86/b3uc21mp/2/

If anyone can help me fix this it would really be appreciated!

Thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="hdr-box">
            <a href="#"><div id="logo"></div></a>

            <nav class="mainnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">New Cars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Used Cars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Servicing</a>
                        <div class="mega-menu">
                            <img src="img/servicing.png" />
                            <h3>Servicing</h3>
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Ut ul tempus tellus.</p>
                            <div class="nav-column">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Book a sevice Online</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Express Service</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Dacia</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lexus</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-column"></div>
                        </div><!-- End of mega menu  -->

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav><!-- End of mainnav -->
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#hdr-box {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}

#logo {
width: 361px;
height: 90px;
background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat;
float: left;
}

.mainnav {
/*font-family: "Myriad Pro", 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;*/
font-size: 20px;
}

#hdr-box nav {
line-height: 30px;
margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 563px;
float: right;
margin-right: 50px;
}

#hdr-box nav ul {list-style: none; margin: 0 auto; width: 800px;}
#hdr-box nav li {float: left; display: inline; margin-right: 40px;}

#hdr-box nav a,  #topbar nav a:visited{
color: #000;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}

#hdr-box nav a:hover {
color: #02a2e0;
}

nav li > .mega-menu {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
width: 770px;
height: 204px;
padding: 40px;
background: #02a2e0;
visibility: hidden;
/*display: none;*/
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
right: 200px;
z-index: 99999;
text-align: left;
list-style: disc;
}

nav li:hover > .mega-menu {
visibility: visible;
display: block;
}

.mega-menu img {
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
width: 272px;
height: 207px;
}

.mega-menu h3 {
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
}

#mainnav ul.mega-menu ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}

#mainav ul.mega-menu li { display: block!important;}

/*nav li > .mega-menu ul ui  {
display: block!important;
color: #fff;

}   

.mainnav ul ul li {
float: none!important;
}*/

.mega-menu p {line-height: 23px;}

.nav-column {width: 135px}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to rebuild css without using IDs, like #hdr-box nav li

Comment: Yeah, this CSS looks pretty messy and your best bet would be to start over and try to limit the number of different stylings that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.nav-column` is inheriting the inline style of `#hdr-box nav li`. Selecting `.nav-column ul li` and delcaring your styles wont override the styles set by `#hdr-box nav li` because IDs are adhered to before classes. Try adding an ID to `.nav-column`.    [**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3uc21mp/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="sub-nav" class="nav-column">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Book a sevice Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Express Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dacia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hyundai</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lexus</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sub-nav ul li {
    float: none ;
    display: block ; 
}
```

Comment: Hi that worked thanks! Its led to another issue now however, if i try to make another column of list items it goes back to displaying horizontally, also i cant change the color of the list items to white as it is taking the css rule from the parent nav still? Any ideas?

**JSFIDDLE:** [link]http://jsfiddle.net/DannyW86/8krqjjj7/1/

Comment: You are using classes in your example, the idea is to use IDs instead http://jsfiddle.net/8krqjjj7/2/

Comment: Yes but if i switch to id the second sublist disappears?

Comment: removing this had no effect on anything i have removed it now.

Comment: It is displaying, you just have other conflicting css you need to fix, expand the view entirely, and you'll css that both menus are there. http://jsfiddle.net/8krqjjj7/3/

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for your help. I'll open a new question like you suggest! Thanks again